# Is there a module that allows incremental increase/decrease on the submit form field?

Tags: entities

Im trying to improve the accuracy of my content creation forms while allowing the same flexibility. I was messing around with airbnb and they have these number fields that get filled out with a + - counter type option (see picture).

1. have + - buttons to increase/decrease the number
2. allow people to type numbers into the field input.
3. force only numbers as input.

[image]
Is there a module that allows for this funciton with a number field?